# FirebaseUI TableViewDataSource Display Data Value

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I am trying to use FirebaseUI to display data in a `UITableViewController`. Everything seems to be working, but it displays the data name instead of the value. My code is below. How could this be changed?

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseUI

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {


  var firebaseRef = Firebase(url:"https://the-lighthouse-app.firebaseio.com/states")
  var dataSource: FirebaseTableViewDataSource!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.dataSource = FirebaseTableViewDataSource(ref: self.firebaseRef, cellReuseIdentifier: "Cell1", view: self.tableView)

    self.dataSource.populateCellWithBlock { (cell: UITableViewCell, obj: NSObject) -> Void in
        let snap = obj as! FDataSnapshot

        // Populate cell as you see fit, like as below
        cell.textLabel?.text = snap.key as String
    }

    self.tableView.dataSource = self.dataSource
  }


  override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
  }


}
```

Comment: Given that you're doing `cell.textLabel?.text = snap.key as String`, I'd indeed expect the cell to display the key/name of the item. What are you trying to display instead? Something like `snap.value.objectForKey("author")` (https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/retrieving-data.html)? Also have a look at the [FirebaseUI sample chat app](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-iOS/tree/master/examples/FirebaseUIChat) to see how it populates the view based on other properties: https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-iOS/blob/master/examples/FirebaseUIChat/FirebaseUIChat/ViewController.m#L35

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I figured it out! I just used `snap.value` and used `as!` and it worked. Thank you for all your help!

Comment: Great to hear! Can you write it up into an answer? Self-answering is encouraged here on StackOverflow and a great way for you to build up your reputation.